# 'Cannot find resource named' when using converter in window definition

Tags: wpf

I have a property in my view model called AreProcessesRunning. When processes are running, I want to disable my window so the user can't click on anything and can't close the window.

In the following code, I can use InverseBooleanConverter for IsEnabled for the Grid. In I use it for IsEnabled for the Window, I get an error saying "Cannot find resource named 'InverseBooleanConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive."

Is there a way I can get around this?

I could create a property called ProcessesAreNotRunning and just bind directly to it. That works, but seems like an odd property to create.

```
<Window
    IsEnabled="{Binding AreProcessesRunning, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">


    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Resources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid
        IsEnabled="{Binding AreProcessesRunning, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `IsEnabled` property of the window is set *before* the `ResourceDictionary` has been loaded.

Either move the resource to `App.xaml` or try to set the `IsEnabled` property *after* you set the `Resources` property:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.IsEnabled>
    <Binding Path="AreProcessesRunning"
             Converter="{StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}"
             Mode="TwoWay" />
</Window.IsEnabled>
```

The third option is to create a new instance of the converter directly without using a resource:

```
<Window.IsEnabled>
    <Binding Path="AreProcessesRunning"
             Mode="TwoWay">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <local:InverseBooleanConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
</Window.IsEnabled>
```

Comment: Thanks. I set the binding using your first example and that works great. All of our windows use the same resource dictionaries, so I should probably just define them in App.xaml.